# at a discount by setting a sale price in addition to the regular price

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I can not understand what is the main meaning here?

> Show people you're selling this product **at a discount by setting a
>   sale price in addition to the regular price**.

From Facebook help.

Answer (score 1):

The part you have emboldened is not really a full clause in itself. The sentence would make more sense to you if you broke it up correctly. The first part tells you *what* to do:

> Show people you're selling this product at a discount...

So it is telling you that if you are selling a product at a discounted price (ie the price you are selling it for is *less* than the recommended retail price) not to simply reduce the price, but also *show* people that you have.

*How* do you do this? The second part of the sentence answers:

> ...by setting a sale price in addition to the regular price.

It is suggesting that you should not only mark the item with your price but also show the *full* price so your customers can see how much discount they are getting.

Example:

> RRP: <s>£199.99</s>
>   OUR PRICE: £179.99!